# Parsing a python dict to a list of values

Tags: python

I am writing a python code, to parse bibtex file:

```
import bibtexparser #to be installed with pip --pre

bibtex_str = """
@ARTICLE{Cesar2013,
  author = {Jean César},
  title = {An amazing title},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {12},
  pages = {12--23},
  journal = {Nice Journal}
}
"""

db = bibtexparser.parse_string(bibtex_str)
print((db.entries[0].fields_dict))
tuples = tuple([
    db.entries[0].fields_dict.get(entry)
    for entry in ["id", "author", "title"]
])
print(tuples)
```

The result is:

```
{'author': Field(key=`author`, value=`Jean César`, start_line=2), 'title': Field(key=`title`, value=`An amazing title`, start_line=3), 'year': Field(key=`year`, value=`2013`, start_line=4), 'volume': Field(key=`volume`, value=`12`, start_line=5), 'pages': Field(key=`pages`, value=`12--23`, start_line=6), 'journal': Field(key=`journal`, value=`Nice Journal`, start_line=7)}
(None, Field(key=`author`, value=`Jean César`, start_line=2), Field(key=`title`, value=`An amazing title`, start_line=3))
```

But, I want the final tuple just as values, eg:

```
(None, 'Jean Cesar', `An amazing title`)
```

I know how to deal with a key-val dict. But I have no idea what the Field is doing here.

How can I get this?

Comment: `Field` is an object created by the library you're using to parse, i.e. bibtex parser, so you need to refer to that to understand how to extract the attributes of `Field` and write them into the form that you need. Have a look at the class definition here https://github.com/sciunto-org/python-bibtexparser/blob/770eb001349dcad48149bc101f07cfc88282d8b3/bibtexparser/model.py#L200

Comment: `.value`? If not obvious from the repr, it's covered in https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/en/main/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mapping of field name to `Field`, so grab the `value` off the `Field`:

```
import bibtexparser

bibtex_str = """
@ARTICLE{Cesar2013,
  author = {Jean César},
  title = {An amazing title},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {12},
  pages = {12--23},
  journal = {Nice Journal}
}
"""

db = bibtexparser.parse_string(bibtex_str)
fields = db.entries[0].fields_dict
t = tuple(
    fields[entry].value if entry in fields else None
    for entry in ["id", "author", "title"]
)
print(t)
```